# Ring.. Proof: $x*0_+=0_+*x=0_+$ , $\forall x \in A$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I must proof that: let $(A; +,*)$ a ring with $+$ and $*$ two binary operation then:

$x*0_+=0_+*x=0_+$ , $\forall x \in A$

First part (i proof that $x*0_+=0_+$): let $x,y \in A$, by hypothesis $A$ is closed for $*$ then $x*y \in A$, by hypothesis $A$ is abelian group then $x*(0_++y)=0_++x*y \in A$, by hypothesis $A$ is a ring then $x*0_++x*y=x*(0_++y)=(0_++x*y) \in A$, but $A$ is abelian group then $x*0_+=x*0_++x*y=x*(0_++y)=(0_++x*y)=0_+ \in A$ therefore $x*0_+=0_+$; in similar mode i must proof that  $0_+*x=0_+$, but I don't  know how to do..

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done the entire proof, but seem to have forgotten right-distributivity. We have, in the same way you explained in your proof, that
$$y*x=(0+y)*x = 0*x+y*x\\
\implies0*x = 0$$

Comment: ok! But $*$ is not commutative..

Comment: It doesn't matter if $*$ is commutative or not, it still distributes over addition (check the definiton of a ring). That means both "sides" distribute, so: $a*(b+c)=a*b+a*c $  and $(b+c)*a=b*a+c*a$

Comment: you're right, I did not remember .... tank you soo much!!!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Or if you were talking to Orlando, I'm sure he is too.

Comment: @Orlando, one moment, but if $x*y=x*(y+0)=x*y+x*0$ then $x*0=0$, but by hypothesis $*$ is distributive over $+$ then $x*y=x*(y+0)=(y+0)*x=y*x+0*x$ then ....?? !! I can't conclude!

Comment: $x*(y+0)=(y+0)*x$ doesn't hold in general. So your middle step doesn't work.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod ok!!

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod, therefore I prove  $0*x=0$ separately from $x*0=0$ and after show that true by transitivity of equality... is it correct?

Comment: @OlegLoMagno Absolutely! You've got it.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod, therefore, by hypothesis we have $x*y=x(y+0)=x*y+x*0$ then $x*0=0$, after by Orlando's proof we have che $0*x=0$ therefore by transitivity of equality then $x*0=0=0*x$... Is it correct? Pardon if I am repetitive but I'm Italian and I don't speak English well...

Comment: That's correct. You have proven exactly what you wanted to.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use $0$ instead of $0_+$ for the zero, or maybe $0_A$.

If you need to prove $0*x=x*0=0 \quad \forall x\in A$

Note that, because $0$ is the identity of the sum, you have $0+0=0$

Therefore

$$(0+0)*x=0*x \iff 0*x+0*x=0*x$$

$$\iff (0*x+0*x)+(-(0*x))=0*x+(-(0*x))$$

$$\iff 0*x+(0*x+(-(0*x)))=0*x+(-(0*x))$$

$$\iff 0*x+0 = 0 \iff 0*x = 0$$

Use the same method to prove $x*0=0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ 0x\, =\, 0+0x\,=\, (-0x + 0x) + 0x\, =\, -0x + (0\!+\!0)x\, =\, -0x + 0x\, =\, 0$